# Seesmic ping vs classic seesmic

Tags: website, twitter

I am trying to figure out what is the difference between seesmic (the one with red theme and raccoon icon), and seesmic ping (the one with green theme and "P" icon).
It seems that old seesmic is replaced by ping, is this correct?